# How to pass string type arguments to c++ methods

Tags: c++, string, arguments

I am a C++ noob, fiddling with the following problem for some hours now. Hopefully, someone can enlighten me.

I had a cpp file with content like so:

test.cpp file content

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using std::cin; using std::endl;
using std::string;


string foobar(string bar) {
  return "foo" + bar;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string bar = "bar";
    System::convCout << "Foobar: " << foobar(bar) << endl;
}
```

This one compiles and runs well. Now I'd like to put foobar into an external library:

mylib.h file content

```
string foobar(string bar);
```

mylib.cpp file content

```
#include <string.h>
using std::cin; using std::endl;
using std::string;

string foobar(string bar) {
  return "foo" + bar;
}
```

test.cpp file content

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mylib.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string bar = "bar";
    System::convCout << "Foobar: " << foobar(bar) << endl;
}
```

I adjusted my Makefile, so that test.cpp compiles and links mylib, but I always encounter the error:

```
test.cpp::8 undefined reference to `foobar(std::string)
```

How do I have to handle string arguments? My attempts seems to be completely wrong here.

Regards
Felix

Comment: Show the complete link statement.

Comment: How did you linked against your external library? Did you forgot to add `-lmylib` to link arguments?

Comment: You do mean to include `<string>` and not `<string.h>`?

Comment: Are you using a pre-standard C++ implementation? Otherwise you need to include `<string>` instead of `<string.h>`, and use `std::string` instead of `string`.

Comment: What language is this? `System::convCout` isn't standard C++.

Comment: The first error seemed to be a linking error, now I get: `error: ‘string’ does not name a type`

Comment: And `#test.cpp file content` is not a preprocessor directive. This file never compiled as C++

Comment: I adjusted the source again to reflect what I have.

Comment: Are you linking `mylib` with your `main`?

Comment: When I do not link mylib I get test.cpp::8 undefined reference to `foobar(std::string)`. When I link it, I get: `error: ‘string’ does not name a type`

Comment: It's `std::string`, not just `string`. Some of your .cpp files have `using std::string` which brings the identifier to global scope, but not all of them do. I suggest you drop `using std::string` altogether and qualify `std::string` everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard library type `std::string` is in the header `string`. To use it, you must include `<string>`, not `<string.h>`. Your `mylib.h` should look something like

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

#include <string>

std::string foobar(std::string bar);

#endif
```

and your `mylib.cpp` should include it:

```
#include "mylib.h"

std::string foobar(std::string bar) {
  return "foo" + bar;
}
```

Note that it may be unnecessary to pass `bar` by value. Looking at your code, a `const` reference might do.

Comment: Thanks! Understood. That works well and produces a mylib.o in my debug folder. When I try to load that object file via ruby ffi (thats the goal), I get an error: only ET_DYN and ET_EXEC can be loaded. I guess, my mylib.o file is not a shared object that can be loaded dynamically by other processes. But how do I achive that?

Comment: @GeorgieF that really depends on your platform. You should look up how to build shared libraries on that platform, but also how to make if all work with ruby ffi (with which I have zero experience).

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately I have a bunch of code prepacked and have to extract some of its functionality into a lib. The Makefile is already there and I tried to create a .a and .so file via `ar rvs foobar.a foobar.o` and `ar crf foobar.so foobar.o`. The results are not loadable by ffi. Since I have no GUI IDE where I could create something new from a template, I am stuck with this here. Thx anyway.